# How to import an Excel sheet into a new SQL table with PowerShell (and autodetect column info)

Tags: sql, excel, powershell, import

So, I spent a fair bit of time figuring this out so thought I'd share (since I didn't find a good example in Stack Overflow) and see if anyone has ideas for improvement.  I'm trying to import an excel worksheet into a new SQL table.  Here's my code...

```
function Import-Excel ($FolderPath, $XlsxFile, $WorksheetNumber, $Server, $Database, $Table) {
    # Open the Excel workbook…
    $Excel = New-Object –ComObject Excel.Application;
    $Workbook = $Excel.WorkBooks.Open((Join-Path –Path (Convert-Path –Path $FolderPath) –ChildPath $XlsxFile));
    $WorkSheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.Item($WorksheetNumber); 
    $StartRow = 2; # …ignore the header row…

    # Create a System.Data.DataTable…
    $DataTable = New-Object –TypeName System.Data.DataTable;
    $null = $DataTable.Columns.Add('Id', 'System.Int32');
    $DataTable.Columns['Id'].AutoIncrement = $true;
    $null = $DataTable.Columns.Add('SERIAL', 'System.String');
    $null = $DataTable.Columns.Add('DESCRIPTION', 'System.String');
    $null = $DataTable.Columns.Add('STATUS', 'System.String');

    # Load the DataTable with the contests of the worksheet
    do {

        $SERIAL = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($StartRow, 2).Value();
        $DESCRIPTION = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($StartRow, 3).Value();
        $STATUS = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($StartRow, 4).Value();
        
        $Row = $DataTable.NewRow();
        $Row.SERIAL = $SERIAL;
        $Row.DESCRIPTION = $DESCRIPTION;
        $Row.STATUS = $STATUS;

        $DataTable.Rows.Add($Row);
        $StartRow++;    
    } while ($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($StartRow, 1).Value() -ne $null); #…until a gap in values…

    $Excel.Quit(); # then exit…

    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Database=$Database;Integrated Security=True;";

    $SqlConnection.Open();

    #Write the data table into a new table in the database
    Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance $Server -DatabaseName $Database -SchemaName "dbo" -TableName $Table -Force -InputData $DataTable

};


Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser
Import-Excel -FolderPath '\\file01\home\RonB\Documents\ExcelImport\' -XlsxFile 'Book1.xlsx' -WorksheetNumber 1 -Server 'MYMACHINE\MYLOCALSERVER' -Database 'ExcelImportTest' -Table 'New_Products_Staging';
```

This works, but some improvement I'd like to see would be to auto-detect the number of columns and column names from the header row, and the data types from the data rows.  This would allow me to have a generic function I could call on any excel sheet (provided it is formatted as a table).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this may be more suited for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com